Why "beacon chain" functionality not just run on the main chain?
I'm interested in consensus engine that interacts with smart contracts during validator selection to select validator (actually I built such a thing and it is operational, link). In proof-of-stake Ethereum, it seems something similar is done but on a "beacon chain" instead of with smart contracts on the main chain. If that is true, is there any crucial reason to not do it on the main chain instead, besides that proof of stake Ethereum was not launched from scratch but had to transform from proof of work Ethereum and this adds a lot of extra complexity?
